# Adding username to profile url

Tags: php, mysql, session, url, get

Have searched the internet far and wide and feel I am getting close.
I want to add a username to a profile.php page through my website.

Currently, the following URL (http://www.example.com/profile.php) displays the necessary profile, but only if you are logged in. In order to visit another members profile, I'd need to know their login information.

However, I'd like the profile.php pages to be unique to a particular user. For Example, http://www.example.com/profile.php?user=CoolDude

I have included the following PHP to get the desired URL with username, except, an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" appears rather than the profile

```
<?php

session_start();
    require_once "includes/define.php";
    $user_row = null;

$user = (isset($_GET['username'])) ? $_GET['username'] : $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user";

$res = mysqli_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=".$_SESSION['username']);
$userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user = $_GET['username'];

header("Location:athleteprofile.php?user=" . $_SESSION['username']);


if (!isset($_SESSION['username'] )) {
    header("Location: login.php"); //login in AdminLogin.php
}

?>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong with the redirects?

Comment: This script always redirects to "Location:ahtleteprofile.php?user=". You´ll never reach the if statement.

Comment: would that be solved with if else?

Comment: username is a string here, so your query failed. However, I don't see where you're querying. You didn't use the right function for this.

Comment: is this not my query? `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user";`

Comment: No, this is invalid `mysqli_real_escape_string("SELECT *`. and this never gets queried neither `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user";`

Comment: Right. allow me check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Script should be in athleteprofile.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "includes/define.php";
$user_row = null;

if (!ISSET($_SESSION['username'] )) {
    header("Location: login.php"); //login in AdminLogin.php
}
if (EMPTY($_GET['user'])) {
    header("Location:athleteprofile.php?user=" . $_SESSION['username']);    
}

$user = $_GET['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$user."'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$username = $userRow['user'];
?>
```

Your script will always redirect regardless $_GET['username'] is set or not.

And please sanitize your $_GET['username'] or even better, use prepared statement

Comment: This appears to be the winner. However, your update with curly brackets around $_SESSION returns an error for me. Removing them helped.

Comment: lol, sorry! i've been searching for the right answer all week. Was very excited to see someone that could help!

Comment: Also, it took me a little more time to edit coz I noticed you didn't execute your query at all.

Comment: doesn't `require_once "includes/define.php";` take care of my database connect? Why do we then need the `$res`?

Answer (score 0):

> **Its Simple You Have TO Use `If`condition:**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once "includes/define.php";
    $user_row = null;

$user = (isset($_GET['username'])) ? $_GET['username'] : $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user";

$res = mysqli_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=".$_SESSION['username']);
$userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user = $_GET['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

header("Location:athleteprofile.php?user=". $_SESSION['username']);
}
elseif(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] !== null) {
    header("Location: login.php"); //login in AdminLogin.php
}

?>
```